# Обновление адаптера RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Я использую `RecyclerView`. В адаптере для него есть `header` который содержит `spinner`, и остальные элементы списка. Я не могу разобраться как на лету подменить остальные элементы не пересоздавая адаптер.

На скриншоте примерная ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что у вас не получается... Вы не знаете о методе `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Действительно не понятно о чём вообще речь, конкретизируйте вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы хотите изменять данные в элементе списка при нажатии на выпадающий список, если так, то вам нужно наследоваться от адаптера и реализовывать всё в методе GetView();